# ASP.Net Authentication with MVC2--how to integrate with DB?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, asp.net-authentication

I'm trying to understand the authentication section of the sample project that opens in a new MVC2 project in VS2010.  It essentially lets you register, login, etc.  I looked through the code that implements this briefly, it looked fairly complicated.  (10 tables, 40 sprocs, 10 views, 4 models, 1 model, 1 controller, etc.)

Is it best to utilize this provided framework for authentication?  If so, how would I integrate this with my own database models (which has user and role tables, etc.).  Also, if I use their framework, are there any performance issues at higher traffic volumes (like SO traffic levels for example), do I need to become responsible for maintaining/backing-up/optimizing the authentication DB as well in this case?

Answer (score 2):

- The default MembershipProvider works fine at higher traffic volumes
- If the default provider does not suit your needs, then you can easily [Implement a custom Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)
- Using the provided interfaces and providers, you get many things for "free". Such as authentication-attributes and integrated security.
- I have never experienced any problems when integrating with custom database models.

Comment: Can you please clarify the free things: "authentication-attributes" and "integrated security", ie what are these and how tare they useful?  With classic ASP we just dropped a cookie with the userID and checked for that, it worked great.  If you used an encrypted cookie that helps with security too.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend two articles, I've implemented my own providers based on fluentNhibernate + my own database structure:

- http://indomitablehef.com/?p=214 (series of posts)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/Fluent-MembershipProvider.aspx (how to write fluent nhibernate providers)